# How do I determine whether the program was built as 32 bit or 64 bit in Go?

Tags: go, 32bit-64bit

The closest I can get is `runtime.GOARCH`, but that might also give `arm`, which could be either 32 or 64 bit.

---

I only care how this program was built, not whether the OS also supports 64-bit executables.  e.g. for ARM mode on an AArch64 CPU or 32-bit compat mode on an x86-64 CPU, I still want 32 because that's the mode this program is running in.

Related: [Detect OS x86 or x64, when compiled as x86 in GO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66254265/detect-os-x86-or-x64-when-compiled-as-x86-in-go) is about detecting what the OS supports, e.g. for maybe running a differently-compiled executable.

Comment: `runtime.GOARCH` will give you the architecture the program was compiled to run on. To get the actual systems' architecture details, you'll probably end up having to check `runtime.GOOS`, and perform a platform specific system call.

Comment: This question originally looked like it was about detecting the OS, but the answers, including the accepted one, were about detecting the compiler-target bitness.  I edited it to make the question match the answers, because this is also a potentially useful thing.  That's why there are comments about this detection not matching the OS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use GOARCH for arm: arm (ARM) and arm64 (AArch64),

> [Optional environment variables](https://golang.org/doc/install/source#environment)
>
> $GOOS and $GOARCH
>
> The name of the target operating system and compilation architecture.
>   These default to the values of $GOHOSTOS and $GOHOSTARCH respectively
>   (described below).
>
> Choices for $GOOS are
>
> ```
> $GOOS     $GOARCH
> darwin    386
> darwin    amd64
> darwin    arm
> darwin    arm64
> dragonfly     amd64
> freebsd   386
> freebsd   amd64
> freebsd   arm
> linux     386
> linux     amd64
> linux     arm
> linux     arm64
> linux     ppc64
> linux     ppc64le
> linux     mips64
> linux     mips64le
> netbsd    386
> netbsd    amd64
> netbsd    arm
> openbsd   386
> openbsd   amd64
> openbsd   arm
> plan9     386
> plan9     amd64
> solaris   amd64
> windows   386
> windows   amd64
> ```

Comment: IIUC, `runtime.GOARCH` would return the architecture of the built *program* being executed. Since some arches, namely, Intel/AMD's 64-bit ISAs, allow running 32-bit programs on 64-bit kernels, so if the OP really wanted to know the architecture of the OS currently executing their Go program, the approach to figuring this out should supposedly be different (and, I'm afraid, platform-specific).

Answer (score 4):

```golang
const is64Bit = uint64(^uintptr(0)) == ^uint64(0)
```

This works because if `uintptr` is 32 bits, `^uintptr(0)` will be `0xffffffff` rather than `0xffffffffffffffff`.

`^uint64(0)` will always be `0xffffffffffffffff` regardless of 32 or 64 bit architectures.

Comment: Wouldn't `uintptr` always be 32-bit in 32-bit code, even when running under a 64-bit OS?  (e.g. i386 code under an x86-64 long mode kernel, or ARM32 code under an AArch64 kernel, are the main real-world use-cases for this.  e.g. where you want to know which version of another executable you can run.)

Comment: But apparently that's what this question actually wants, given the accepted answer.  So I'll retitle the question.

Comment: Note that this will report non-64-bit even for ILP32 ABIs in 64-bit mode.  So this is good for figuring out if pointers are 64-bit, but not for figuring out if 64-bit integer stuff can be done fully efficiently.  (e.g. AArch64 ILP32 uses 32-bit pointers in 64-bit mode to save space, same as [Linux x32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) on x86-64)

Comment: Hmm interesting. Then perhaps a second test `uint64(^uint(0)) == ^uint64(0)` would give a fuller picture.

Comment: I wouldn't expect `uint` to be 64-bit, if Go sizes it like C compilers choose the size of `unsigned int`.  ILP32 ABIs like x32 will have 32-bit `uint` as well, I'd expect.

Comment: But generally for anyone using this kind of trick, they're really interested in whether uint will be 32 or 64 bit, and whether uintptr will be 32 or 64 bit. I've encountered this issue many times when trying to deal with for example words in a big.Int

Comment: I don't know Go, but if you're writing your own extended-precision stuff, you generally want to work in chunks as large as efficiently possible, even if that's wider than pointer width.  (Or maybe just always 64-bit chunks, even if that means the compiler has to use a pair of 32-bit `add/adc` instructions in a 32-bit build).  If you want to know whether `uint64` is as efficient as a 32-bit integer type for most arithmetic, in C/C++ AFAIK there's no easy portable way to detect that without false negatives on ILP32 ABIs.  uintptr being 64-bit is a sure sign that it *is* efficient, though.